# Is it possible to have an IOS emulator in Windows 10 or not?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, dart

As a fresher in Flutter I  started developing my first app in flutter using VS Code in windows 10  and run it in android mobile. It was working correctly . Now i need to run my app in IOS simulator  also.Is it possible to have an IOS simulator  in windows 10 to use with Visual Studio Code or not?

Comment: No.. you can not develop ios apps on windows... you need mac for that

Answer (score 0):

IOS Emulator doesn't work on windows you're gonna have to use Virtual machine "VMware" or "Oracle VM VirtualBox" in order to use Xcode "Emulator".

These 2 links might be helpful each on represent a certain version of IOS, and you decide according to the version of XCode you wanna use:

[Catalina](https://www.geekrar.com/download-macos-catalina-vmware-virtualbox-image-latest-version/)
[Mojave](https://www.geekrar.com/download-macos-mojave-vmware-virtualbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run an iOS emulator on a Windows 10. For now it's not posible. I also wanted to use one when developing with Xamarin Forms but the only way is to have as other answers said a Virtual Machine or a Phyisical Device. Also you can pay someone to host a emulator for you, there are lots of them on internet offering this service.

Answer (score 0):

Running an iOS simulator on Windows 10 is not supported, as it requires a macOS environment.

To test iOS apps, you'll need access to a Mac device.

Alternatively, certain companies provide **cloud-based Mac services**, enabling you to rent a macOS machine for a specific duration. You can then **remotely connect** to this Mac from your Windows PC to develop and test iOS applications.

Other than that what you can do is you can try setting up **Mac OS on your PC through Virtual Box or VM ware systems**.